# Qt c++ QFile writes only last input

Tags: qt, qfile

I have a function saveResolvedInfo() that should save each resolved ip address from structure _ResolvedInfo to an ip.txt file:

```
void saveResolvedInfo()
{
_ResolvedInfo rf;
QFile file("ip.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream out(&file);

out << rf.country << " " << rf.ip << "/n";
}
```

Well, it only writes last resolved ip address. Any ideas whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Each call kills the previous content, so you are only seeing the result of the last one.

This happens because by default when you open a `QFile` specifying `QIODevice::WriteOnly` the existing data is destroyed, as explained [in the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum):

> `QIODevice::WriteOnly` The device is open for writing. Note that this mode implies Truncate.
>
> `QIODevice::Truncate` If possible, the device is truncated before it is opened. All earlier contents of the device are lost.

If you want to keep the existing file content, you have to pass the `QIODevice::Append` flag.

> `QIODevice::Append` The device is opened in append mode so that all data is written to the end of the file.

```
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text);
```